# Repeat word with delete and space in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

Not sure if this is possible in MySQL, but I have a column that has business names like:

AT&T Store
O'Reilly's Auto Parts
Burger King

which I import into Sphinx Search with a MySQL query.  I have MariaDB, so there is a REGEXP_REPLACE(col, regexp, replace) function, but I'm having trouble figuring out the rest.

What I need is to repeat words with non-alphanumeric characters replaced with and without a space.  So the above examples would become:

ATT AT T Store
OReillys O Reilly s Auto Parts
Burger King

Is this possible in a MySQL query?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEXP_REPLACE is in MariaDB only, MySQL doesn't have it.

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
"AT&T Store
O'Reilly's Auto Parts
Burger King",
'([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)',
'\\1\\2\\3 \\1 \\2 \\3'),
'([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)',
'\\1\\2 \\1 \\2')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Just substituted the names listed with the column, and it performed well on all of it.  Also had to upgrade to MariaDB 10, as 5.5 doesn't support regexp_replace.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, to do this in PHP for inserting, I was able to use: preg_replace('~([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)~','\\1\\2 \\1 \\2', preg_replace('~([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)[[:punct:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)~','\\1\\2\\3 \\1 \\2 \\3', $VariableOrString));

Answer (score 2):

This can be done all at once, but maybe not by SQL primitive regex.

I don't know REGEXP_REPLACE, nor modern day SQL.

Typically its done by three regex.

Pseudo code:

```
$column_val = "O'Reilly's Auto Parts";
$new_column_val = Replace_Globally(  
                     $column_val,
                     '\b\w+[[:punct:]](?:[[:punct:]]*\w)+\b',  
                     function( $match ) {
                            $val = $match.value;
                            $text1 = Replace_Globally( $val, '[[:punct:]]+', "" ); 
                            $text2 = Replace_Globally( $val, '[[:punct:]]+', " " ); 
                            return $text1 + " " + $text2;
                      }
                  );
```

So, this might not look like something sql can do, so you might have to get creative.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a shot, and see what I can get to work.